# Exception when cloning Azure.Devops Repository

Tags: git, clone, azure, visual-studio-2017

I can clone repositories from my work's repo fine. I switched DevOps and VisualStudio to my personal Microsoft account to do some DevOps tutorials. Whenever I attempt to clone I get the following exception:

Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
NullReferenceException encountered.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
NullReferenceException encountered.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
cannot spawn /c/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2017/professional/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-askpass.exe: No such file or directory
could not read Username for 'https://dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled

I tried downloading the latest of Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows-master but I don't see any dlls. I also checked the WindowForGit in the VisualStudioInstaller in hopes that would install the latest. I keep getting the same exception.

---

I still can't clone the repository connected to my google account. I can easily clone the repository connected to my work account. It may be an issue with being connected to multiple organizations.

---

When I removed my personal google account I stopped getting this error. I'm not marking this as answered because I am unable to connect to both accounts.